# android emulator is running slow

Tags: android, emulation

How to speedup android emulator.  I am using windows xp system with amd sempron processor  . I cant use haxm of intel because mine is not intel processor. So anyone can guide me to speedup android emulator

Comment: emulators are usually very slow after api 19 system image, use genymotion if you can. check use HOST GPU if you have to have emulator

Comment: don't expect much improvement... I'm not a huge fan of Apple, but when it comes to Android emulators, it's much faster than anything I've seen on Windows. Besides a connected device.

Answer (score -1):

You can try [Genymotion.](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide)

Genymotion is an Android emulator which comprises a complete set of sensors and features in order to interact with a virtual Android environment. With Genymotion, you can test your Android applications on a wide range of virtual devices for development, test and demonstration purposes.

eclipse plugin link: http://plugins.genymotion.com/eclipse